# $.ajax and php responses

Tags: php, ajax, http-headers, response

When i make requests this way i never get the response to manipulate .
Well i get as response 
***Array
(
    [name] => Mastering React Native (2).pdf
    [type] => application/pdf
   ...
but i need to show to user the file info.

```
  <form id='formid'>
        <input id='fileid' type='file' name='file1' hidden/>
        <input type='submit' value='IMPORT'/>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fdat = new FormData(this);
            fdat.append('operation', 'IMPORT');
            function importFile() {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: "data-source/oracle_controller_upload.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: fdat,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(response){
                                   }
                });
            }
            debugger;
            importFile().done(function (result) {
            }).fail(function () {
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my php code:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['operation'] === "IMPORT" && $_FILES) {
    echo print_r($_FILES['file1']);
    return;
}
```

Cant reach either the **success callback** or **done()**.
Any help?

Comment: You haven't said what behaviour you _do_ get, or any errors etc, but I would guess your page posts back first. You need to write `e.preventDefault();` as the first line inside your function, to stop the default submit action from posting the whole page back. $.ajax returns a Promise, so returning that from the "submit" handler makes no sense - normally you'd return a boolean, if anything

Comment: Also your "done" appears to be waiting on a separate function, nothing to do with your form submit. What does "importFile()" do?

Comment: off course i have  e.preventDefault();

Comment: response is Array
(
    [name] => Mastering React Native (2).pdf
    [type] => application/pdf
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpowYZ4I
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 20671375
)

Comment: Lastly now I've formatted your code properly, it's clear you have a syntax error - there's a stray } in the middle. And even if you remove that, importFile() will never run because the function returns before that.

Comment: "off course i have e.preventDefault();". How should I know that? You should post your real code if you don't want to mislead people. Code that's different to the real code is just going to waste time.

Comment: So there _is_ some kind of response, then? Where is that response being seen? In your Network tab? In the main browser window? You aren't explaining this very well - you've seemingly posted code that isn't your real code, and you're being vague about exactly what is happening.

Comment: updated code now

Comment: response is ------  
 Array ( [name] => Mastering React Native (2).pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpowYZ4I [error] => 0 [size] => 20671375 )

Comment: yes you said that. What I asked was _where_ exactly you are seeing it? In the main browser window? In your network tab when you view the ajax request? Can you be sure that the ajax request definitely runs? Does your our first "debugger" point trigger to show that the JavaScript runs and calls the importFile function?

Comment: Ok hang on I think I figured it. Will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said exactly, but I think you must be getting an error about an invalid JSON response. Your ajax request is expecting JSON back from the server, but you're just sending a raw string dump of your variable.

In the PHP, do this:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['operation'] === "IMPORT" && $_FILES) {
    echo json_encode($_FILES['file1']); //encode the object as JSON instead of just a variable dump
    return;
}
```

and in your .done() method:

```
importFile().done(function (result) {
  alert(result.name); //just for example, to display the name in an alert
  //...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with

```
if (@$_REQUEST['operation'] === "IMPORT" && $_FILES) {
  echo json_encode($_FILES['file1']);
  return;
}
```

I have `dataType: "JSON"`, so of course the response must be JSON.